# $ionicPlatform.ready not firing when deploying to real device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having this strange problem, I am developing an android app using ionic framework and using cordova plugins to access native android functions.
those plugins as suggested by cordova documentation should be called when $ionicPlatform.ready event is fired so I am enclosing my code which includes cordova functions within:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
// some cordova plugin code e.g $cordovaVibration.vibrate([100]);
})
```

the strange behaviour is whenever I test my app on real device using this command:

```
$ ionic run android -c -l
```

all functions work perfectly with no errors.
now when I build and sign my app, then deploy it to the same real device the

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
//some code
})
```

executes only once inside the angular.module(....).run(...){...}
and only after I lock the screen and then unlock it.
and then all code inside

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
//some code
})
```

won't work.
this is the code in app.js:

```
angular.module('conFusion', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'app.controllers','app.services'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicLoading, $cordovaSplashscreen, $timeout) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    $timeout(function() {
      $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
    }, 3000);
  });
// the rest of code goes here
```

as you can see the $cordovaSplashscreen.hide(); cannot be executed unless $ionicPlatform.ready is fired. the thing is the splash screen is hidden only when I lock the screen then unlock it but the code belonging to other plugins is never executed.

**UPDATE**

changed the listener form $ionicPlatform.ready to

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady(){ .... }
```

of no avail.

when testing the app with

```
$ cordova run android
```

or

```
$ ionic run android
```

the code enclosed in listener function won't execute.
but when testing the app with command:

```
$ ionic run android -c -l
```

the app works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
   $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
}
```

try using this event listener inside your $ionicPlatform.ready funtion . Maybe that will help you (y) :)

Comment: thank you but problem not solved, I used the listener you suggested still the problem persisting,but I discovered one more thing when testing with the command $cordova run android I get similar behaviour to when running the released apk, while when testing with $ ionic run android -c -l everything works fine so I guess the error in the build system ?? I tried $ ionic build android --release of no avail.

Comment: you can also alter your splashscreen behaviour by modifying your config.xml like <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="6000"/> ... There are so much you can acheive by modifying these :)

Comment: thank you but the problem is not with the splash screen, its with the event not firing or the listener not hearing it !! I updated the problem description to tell that the splashscreen is only hidden when I lock the screen and then unlock it (apparently this fires deviceready event ??)

Comment: exactly what is your requirement ? Your splashscreen is not hiding itself ?

Comment: my requirement is that 'deviceready' event not firing, It signals that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access. those APIs are necessary for my ionic app to access notifications,toast,camera,gallery, and vibration. so this mean Cordova APIs have not loaded, this is strange because this problem does not happen when I run the app with live reload.

Answer (score 0):

After A LOT of inspection I was finally able to determine the cause and fix it.

the problem was with this exact cordova plugin:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git

I just removed it and voila !!! everything functions normally no more strange behaviour.

one useful tool I found is this chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb/dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage
it allows for remote debugging using console.log(); instruction within the Ionic app.